# Use LINQ to Return a List of Items that Match an ID in a List inside a List of Items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items like so:

```
Item item = new Item {ID = 1, Name = 'One'};
Item item2 = new Item {ID = 2, Name = 'Two'};
List<Item> items = new List<Item>;
items.Add(item);
items.Add(item2);
```

Then I have another list of other items, with a list inside that is a list of associations to the first item list:

```
OtherItem otherItem = new OtherItem {ID = 1, Name = 'OtherOne', ListOfItems = {1,2}};
OtherItem otherItem2 = new OtherItem {ID = 2, Name = 'OtherTwo', , ListOfItems = {2}};
List<OtherItem> otherItems = new List<OtherItem>;
otherItems.Add(otherItem);
otherItems.Add(otherItem2);
```

Now, I want to return a list of Item that are included in the OtherItem ListOfItems. FOr example's sake, how would I return a list of Item where OtherItem's ListOfItems includes ID: 1?

Comment: you need to select from items where item's id is contained by array of ids where is the problem?

Comment: Give me an example in an answer?

Comment: well direct translation from english should do the trick ... the only trick is "is contained" - you should reverse it to array of ids contains item's id in where ... even methods are the same as I wrote *edit:* `items.Where(item => otherItem.ListOfItems.Contains(i=>i==item.ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items.Where(i => otherItems.Any(oi => oi.ListOfItems.Any(li => li == i.ID)))
```

Comment: The ID of Item is contained in the ListOfItems on the OtherItem object. This doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where`:

```
List<OtherItem> otherItems = new List<OtherItem>
{
    new OtherItem { ID = 1, Name = "OtherOne", ListOfItems = { 1, 2 } },
    new OtherItem { ID = 2, Name = "OtherTwo", ListOfItems = { 2 } }
};
var ID = 1;
var result = otherItems.Where(s => s.ListOfItems.Any(x => x == ID))
    .Select(s => new { s.ID, s.Name });
```

Comment: Except I want to select a list of Item. Not OtherItem.